# Redis loosing connection when used with Celery groups or chain - throwing ERROR/MainProcess] Connection to Redis lost: Retry (0/20) now

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

My problem is with redis showing the following error in terminal when i start my worker using celery task.

I am lucky to have reproduce the error using a modified version of chord in [celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords). It seems the problem happens with chord or where I have too many groups running in parallel i.e `chord(add.s(i, i) for i in range(1, num))(list_add.s())`  or `group(add.s(i, i) for i in range(1, num))()`

Below is my code sample

```
@task
def add(x, y):
    return [x, y, x + y, "Next"]

@task
def list_add(nums):
    numbers = []
    count = 1
    for i in nums:
        print("{}). {}".format(count, i))
        numbers.extend(i)
        count += 1
    print(numbers)
    return numbers

@task
def foo(num):
    return chord(add.s(i, i) for i in range(1, num))(list_add.s())
```

**Below is part of my terminal output with traceback.**

```
    [2015-11-04 20:36:14,912: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: b2b.tasks.add[b87fdc44-e759-4224-bce4-11f9468d12b3]
[2015-11-04 20:36:14,913: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: b2b.tasks.add[120f5bf2-b962-4424-894b-d6f0ca56102b]
[2015-11-04 20:36:14,914: INFO/MainProcess] Task b2b.tasks.bar[9dc93c75-6404-4db3-a685-ff91460e1adb] succeeded in 1.00830382s: <AsyncResult: c891df3e-aa5c-4c9f-ad3f-30abe3b3ccc1>

    [2015-11-04 19:44:34,922: ERROR/MainProcess] Connection to Redis lost: Retry (0/20) now.
    [2015-11-04 19:44:34,922: ERROR/MainProcess] Connection to Redis lost: Retry (1/20) in 1.00 second.
    ...
    /Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py:365: RuntimeWarning: Exception raised outside body: ConnectionError('Error 8 connecting to localhost:6379. nodename nor servname provided, or not known.',):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 235, in trace_task
      File "/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 256, in store_result
      File "/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 490, in _store_result
      File "/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 160, in set
      File "/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 149, in ensure
      File "/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 243, in retry_over_time
      File "/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 169, in _set
      File "/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2593, in execute
      File "/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2447, in _execute_transaction
      File "/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 532, in send_packed_command
      File "/Users/Michael/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 436, in connect
    ConnectionError: Error 8 connecting to localhost:6379. nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
```

This is the command i use to start my worker in terminal
celery -A scraper worker -P eventlet -c 1000 -l info

> It works fine when foo() is passed 20 but with 1000 or greater the
>   error shows up.

```
>>> a = foo.delay(20)     # works 
>>> a = foo.delay(1000)   # fails
```

Please, kindly suggest how this can be solved if you have an idea and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out with help from IRC and Greg from [redis user groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/zhx6wA4Tku0)

By changing the limit of opened files on my Mac OSX Yosemite to 65536 the problem was solved.

I hope this helps someone someday.